# Symfony : cannot use env() function

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to load a .env variable using

```
$configFirstLevel = env('config_level1');
```

But i'm getting this error :

```
Error: Call to undefined function Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\Configurator\env()
```

Any idea why I have this please ?

Comment: The php function is named `getenv()`.

Comment: And assuming (based on the tag) you are using the Symfony framework then you should be injecting your env values.  In a Symfony app you very seldom need to directly access env variables.

Answer (score -2):

Reason seems to be pretty simple: you have required `symfony/dependency-injection` but `Symfony\Component\Config\Resource\ClassExistenceResource` obviously belongs to `symfony/config`. If you will review dependencies of `symfony/dependency-injection` you will see that it requires `symfony/config` only as dev dependency. Hence simple inclusion of `symfony/config` should fix the issue.

Comment: And what exactly does any of that have to do with an undefined env function?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).